# In React-Native, how can I get to .push() a screen from a modal screen using react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm displaying a full screen modal using react navigation.

How can I push some other screens without closing the modal ?

Calling navigation.push('test') does not seem to work.

Is it even feasible ?